# Android development environment in ubuntu?

Tags: android, eclipse

I'm a new android developer and i want to coding in unbun.I download the sdk in http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html,but when i open the eclipse,it alert a error

```
[2014-03-05 22:01:39 - adb] Unexpected exception 'Cannot run program "/usr/local/bin/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20131030/sdk/platform-tools/adb": error=2, 没有那个文件或目录' while attempting to get adb version from '/usr/local/bin/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20131030/sdk/platform-tools/adb',i am confused with this question,who can help me?
```

Comment: If you have a 64-bit system and a 32-bit version of the sdk, you may need to install 32-bit support libraries.  Or it could be a permission issue.  Or possibly the SDK is simply not fully installed.  Hopefully you unpacked it on the target system and not some other system and then tried to move the files over.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is Java installed?  Can you access it from the command line - IOW what does:

java --version

return?

Is this version compatible with the Android SDK you've installed?

Can you run adb commands from the command line?

Is Eclipse configured with to use your installed versions of Java and Android SDK?

What user is Eclipse running as?  Does that user have execute permissions for Java and the Android SDK?

Comment: java is unlikely to be an issue for the adb tool (a native executable built from C source), in fact missing java would keep eclipse itself from running so this error message never would have been generated.

Comment: this link http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html says JDK 6 is required and you cannot use gcj

Comment: That still has nothing to do with an **adb** error.

Comment: true enough.  i've gotten accustomed to thinking of them as all one thing.

Answer (score 1):

On Linux you need to install IA32 library as well.

Try this:

```
    apt-get install ia32-libs
```

You can no longer install ia32-libs, so you must the individual 32 bit libraries needed by adb

```
   sudo apt-get install libc6-i386 lib32stdc++6 lib32gcc1 lib32ncurses5
```

And for Ubuntu 13.10:

```
   sudo apt-get install libc6-i386 lib32stdc++6 lib32gcc1 lib32ncurses5 lib32z1
```